# Installation problems of Ubuntu via virtualBox in my windows 7 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, windows-7, virtualbox, 64-bit

I am really unhappy while installing Ubuntu 14.4.01 via virtualBox in my windows 7 Professional 64 bit operating system.

***I am using VirtualBox-4.3.14-95030-Win

I am finding these problems while installing:

1. >>>When I click on "Start" for the installation, I have found this message:

"VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinInstallHooks"

"Failed to install NtCreateSection monitor: e9 5b eb 15 0 0 0 0f 5 c3 f 1f 44 0 
0
(rc=-8)"

1. >>>Then when I am clicking on "abort" button I have found this:

"VirtualBox - Error

"Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.
The virtual machine Ubuntu has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1

Details:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} "

So, how can I solve the problem?

Please, reply as early as possible.

Waiting for your reply...

Mahtab.

Comment: I have disabled the antivirus its works for me....error gone

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link 
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615#p292873
Seems the same follows with you too

Comment: Try to disable the antivirus program if any before running on virtual box please

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, edit to include more details, don't comment below.